# Which country in South East Asia will be cheapest to import and register an imported car?

Tags: automobiles, southeast-asia, overland, import-taxes, registration

I want to drive a car from Europe to South East Asia, probably a 40-year old Volvo Laplander C304 valued at around 10000 EUR, and then leave the vehicle registered in my name anywhere in South East Asia, for me to use next time I come there.

In which South East Asian country the registration fees and taxes will be the lowest?

Any country in South East Asia as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southeast_Asia is fine, except perhaps Philippines (unless there is a car-carrying ferry connection from mainland Asia to Philippines that I don't know of or a way to ship it there for less then the difference in cost of registration and taxes elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Can't answer for other countries, but to permanently import a personal vehicle into Thailand (ie: to register it and leave it there) you need to have a Non-Immigrant visa, work permit and reside in Thailand for a year.  So likely not really practical for your situation (I am guessing you plan to fly home, earn more money and return later to continue your drive).

You might get away under temporary import rules if you are able to drive the car out of Thailand within six months of arrival, but it wouldn't be registered there, just simply allowed to stay in the country.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do: fly to Europe, and then return to South-East Asia later to continue my trip. Looking for the cheapest way to legally keep the vehicle stored in SEA for several months (I could be away 9 months).

Comment: Best bet is to search the websites of the custom department for countries in SE Asia for vehicle import rules.  They would be your most accurate source for rules and paperwork required.